# Does casting a pointer to pointer reference lead to undefined behaviour?

Tags: c++, casting, reference, strict-aliasing

I ran into the following ugly bit of code and wanted to know what does the standard have to say about it. Is the call to foo() considered to cause undefined behaviour? Or is it harmless?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Base {};
class Derived : public Base {};

void foo(Base *&b)
{
  std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  Derived *der = new Derived();

  foo((Base *&)der);

  return 0;
}
```

I believe the ugly c-cast was done because a simple (Base *) cast would cause a compilation error.
Even still, does it compile now only because of strict aliasing? Or is a cast to reference permitted by the standard?

Comment: Yes, this is a strict aliasing violation

Comment: @M.M Could you elaborate in an answer?

Comment: @M.M I second lubgr. Would be glad if you can give some reference source or explanation to your comment.

Comment: A reference to read up on [strict aliasing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing).

Comment: Just imagine what will happen if `Derived` have more than one base class and you cast to base which is not located at start of object.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite UB, because you are effectively *reinterpreting* the derived pointer as a base pointer. The reason for that is that you are not converting a `Derived` pointer to a `Base` pointer, but rather a `T&` to an `U&` - and while `T` and `U` are of the same size and alignment (both are object pointer types), they are not `static_cast`-able into one another. This in turn requires the C-style cast to behave as an `reinterpret_cast`.

While it will usually (tm) work in practice in your case (the base subobject is located at index 0 of the derived object), it will be expected to (tm) fail when you are using multiple or virtual inheritance.

The intended effect can be quite easily reached by performing the following operation:

```
Derived* der = new Derived();
Base* base = der; // conversion to base
foo(base);
der = static_cast<Derived*>(base); // assumes that whatever base points to now is also (derived from) Derived
```

Note that using references in casts is not, generally speaking, a problem. For example:

```
Derived derived;
Base& base = static_cast<Base&>(derived); // equivalent to *static_cast<Base*>(&derived)
```

Comment: Nitpick : different pointer types are not guaranteed to have the same size (or alignment). For an actual implementation, it's a reasonable assumption to make though, especially when talking about pointers to derived and base classes.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker The question indicated that the program in this form was not rejected by the compiler due to an invalid cast (and yes, I am to lazy to look up if that diagnostic is required ;) ).